# angularJS unit testing a scope variable inside of promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, promise, angular-promise

How do I unit test a $scope variable inside of a .then()?

I'm trying to unit test a function that calls an external API and in the .then() of the apicall handles the errors/success of that api call.

```
function submitPayment() {
        //Create post object based off the selected payment method
        var postObj = {
            'premiumDue' : $scope.premiumDue, 
            'effectiveDate' : $scope.effectiveDate
        };

        myPayService.submitPayment(postObj).then(function(responseData){
            if(!responseData.errors) {
                $scope.transactionDetails = [
                    {
                        id: 'transaction-date',
                        label: 'Transaction Date',
                        value: $scope.formattedCurrentDate
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'ammount',
                        label: 'Ammount',
                        value: "$"+$scope.premium.toFixed(2)
                    },      
                ];
            } else {
                $scope.submitError = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

This is very simple, and it works in practice but I'm not sure how to structure a unit test around it. I want to test and expect that mockedTransactionDetails = $scope.transactionDetails.

How do I unit test this function to test for that? Everytime I try I'm getting that $scope.transactionDetails is undefined.

My unit test so far:

```
it('should handle submit payment success and set transaction details', function () {
                //set up transaction details now
                $scope.premium = 123.45;
                $scope.effectiveDate = "2016-01-01";
                $scope.formattedCurrentDate = "2016-01-04";

                var submitData = {
                    'premiumDue' : $scope.premium, 
                    'effectiveDate' : $scope.effectiveDate
                };
                var result;
                var promise = myPayService.submitPayment(submitData);
                var mockTransactionDetails = [
                    {
                        id: 'transaction-date',
                        label: 'Transaction Date',
                        value: $scope.formattedCurrentDate
                    },
                    {
                        id: 'ammount',
                        label: 'Ammount',
                        value: "$"+$scope.premium.toFixed(2)
                    },  
                ];

                //Resolve the promise and store results
                promise.then(function(res) {
                    result = res;
                });
                //Apply scope changes
                $scope.$apply();
                expect(mockTransactionDetails).toEqual($scope.transactionDetails);
            });
```

Result is coming out to an empty object and $scope.transactionDetails is undefined. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should really reduce your question to a tiny reproducible example so that we can answer without going all that trouble of understanding your code.

Comment: @mostruash i added a line at the top -- How do I unit test a $scope variable inside of a .then()?

If I don't include enough code then people complain, if I do include all the code then people complain. Quite a catch-22 here sometimes.

Comment: Normally, calling $scope.$apply() executes all thenables so you can test your $scope variables. There must be another fault in your code or in the way that you are testing.

Comment: How are you mocking `myPayService.submit`?

Comment: @Chanthu -- `$provide.service('myPayService', function() {
     this.submitPayment = jasmine.createSpy('submitPayment').and.callFake(mockPromise);
    });` the mockPromise then calls any callback provided.   IE: `function mockPromise() {
   return {
    then: function(callback) {
     if (callback) {
      callback(mockResponse);
     }
    }
   }
  }`